# Is it possible to sync Remember The Milk with emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, productivity, org-mode, rememberthemilk

I have just started using [Org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) in emacs, and I am very impressed. However, I currently have all of my todo's in [Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com)

The simplest solution would be to export RTM into an org-mode document - is there an automated way to do this? It would be even better if I could sync RTM with org-mode so that I can continue to use both interchangeably.

What solutions exist for linking these two applications?

Answer (score 5):

It's not a two-way solution, but you could use the feeds that RTM makes available:

- RTM RSS feeds: http://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/answers/atom/rss.rtm
- Org mode RSS feeds: https://orgmode.org/manual/RSS-Feeds.html

This was also mentioned in this answer to a SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138947/is-there-a-solution-to-automatically-synchronize-emacs-org-mode-with-one-of-the-w#2141906